# Snakemake workflow in which wildcards produce different output files

Tags: python, automation, snakemake

I am building a snakemake workflow in which certain wildcards(populations) have extra steps not shared by all wildcards. I have 8 populations that run a pedigree-based evaluation, and 6 of these 8 populations run, in addition to the pedigree evaluation, a genomic evaluation. My workflow includes a Python script that only generates a genotype file in the case of a population in the genomic workflow. A summary of the issue is given below. The population CHA runs with the genomic workflow, and the population BEL works with the pedigree-based workflow. In the case of the BEL wildcard, the Python script produces the `[dlistAnim, phen_file]` files, and in the case of the CHA wildcard, the Python script produces `[dlistAnim, phen_file, gen_file]`.

```
genomic_breeds = {"CHA": "CHAROLAIS"}
breeds = {"CHA": "CHAROLAIS",  "BEL":"BELGIAN BLUE"}


rule extract_phenotype_data:
    input:
        
    params:
        config = "../config_file.yml",
        breed =f"{{breed}}"
    output:
        dlistAnim=f"../listcodeall{{breed}}.txt",
        phen_file=f"../phen_{{breed}}.txt",
        gen_file=f"../genotypes_{{breed}}.txt"
    run:
        cmd = f"python /../extract_phenotype_data_for_populations.py --config {params.config} --breed {breeds[params.breed]}"
        shell(cmd)
```

The file `gen_file` is required by the steps after the pedigree-based evaluation that should run for only the genomic breeds (CHA) wildcards.

I have tried the dynamic file command, however, I run into a bug that refers me to https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/823.

I would expect a workflow that runs for all wildcards to a certain level and then continues for a subset of the wildcards to the end. Additionally, the workflow should account for the files that may not be present in the pedigree-based workflow.

The snakemake version is 7.25.0

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you formulate your situation and describe the problem you want to solve in more general terms understandable to folks without your specific-field background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this question by using two rules in combination with the wildcard constraints directive.

The first rule produces two outputs and only works on wildcards **not in** the `genomic_breeds` dictionary.

```
rule extract_phenotype_data:
        wildcard_constraints:
        breed='|'.join([breed for breed in breeds.keys() if not breed 
        in genomic_breeds])
    input:
        
    params:
        config = "../config_file.yml",
        breed =f"{{breed}}"
    output:
        dlistAnim=f"../listcodeall{{breed}}.txt",
        phen_file=f"../phen_{{breed}}.txt",
    run:
        cmd = f"python /../extract_phenotype_data_for_populations.py 
        --config {params.config} --breed {breeds[params.breed]}"
        shell(cmd)
```

The second rule uses the wildcard constraints directive as well and only works on wildcards **in** the `genomic_breeds` dictionary.

```
rule extract_phenotype_data_genomic:
    wildcard_constraints:
        breed='|'.join(list(genomic_breeds.keys()))
    input:
        
    params:
        config = "../config_file.yml",
        breed =f"{{breed}}"
    output:
        dlistAnim=f"../listcodeall{{breed}}.txt",
        phen_file=f"../phen_{{breed}}.txt",
        gen_file=f"../genotypes_{{breed}}.txt"
    run:
        cmd = f"python /../extract_phenotype_data_for_populations.py --config {params.config} --breed {breeds[params.breed]}"
        shell(cmd)
```

The output of both rules are different in that only one of the rules produces the `../genotypes_{{breed}}.txt` file.

Rule All can be defined as

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(f"../phen_{{breed}}.txt", breed=breeds.keys()),
        expand(f"../listcodeall{{breed}}.txt", breed=breeds.keys()),
        expand(f"../genotypes_{{breed}}.txt", breed =genomic_breeds.keys()),
```

Perhaps this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with two separate rules, an input function, and rule order.  The idea is that for some wildcards the input function will raise an exception causing the *other* rule to run.

```
genomic_breeds = {"CHA": "CHAROLAIS"}
breeds = {"CHA": "CHAROLAIS",  "BEL":"BELGIAN BLUE"}

ruleorder:
    do_pedigree_with_genome > do_pedigree  # always try the genome version first

def do_pedigree_with_genome_input(wildcards):
    if wildcards.breed not in genomic_breeds:
        raise ValueError()  # this breed shouldn't use this rule
    return ...

rule do_pedigree_with_genome:
    input:
        do_pedigree_with_genome_input
    output:
        dlistAnim=f"../listcodeall{{breed}}.txt",
        phen_file=f"../phen_{{breed}}.txt",
        gen_file=f"../genotypes_{{breed}}.txt"

rule do_pedigree:
    output:
        dlistAnim=f"../listcodeall{{breed}}.txt",
        phen_file=f"../phen_{{breed}}.txt",
    ...
```

So `CHA` will first try to use the genome version of the rule and run because it is one of the genomic_breeds.  `BEL` will also try the genome version, but the value error will cause it to use the regular version instead.

As a side effect, if you try to consume the gen_file of a breed not in the genomic_breeds, snakemake will raise an exception because no rule is available to produce it.